# No script Tag when js is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

Is there any one who tried checking " no script" tag in detail. Will this "no script" tag can execute or pull a link that I have specified through a link element or an img src element if javascript is disabled.

Problem that I have here is this... I have visitors to my website and I am trying to track users which comes with browser but with javascript not enabled.

I added iframe, img, link tags inside "no script" tag to track users without javascript so that it will add a log for me when no-js users visit the page. But looks like "no script" doesn't get executed.

I can only add iframe or js elements and I can't add server side scripts to track these users.

== Edited

I have tried adding no script tag in body element with a tag like this.

```
<noscript><img src=example.com/log></noscript> 

<noscript><link src=example.com/log></noscript> 

<noscript><iframe src=example.com/log></noscript>
```

This gets triggered when I run this from Mozilla with js disabled. But when real traffic is hitting my site, this no script tag doesn't get executed. basically I am trying to figure out the visitors who is coming with a browser enabled but somehow the no script tag is not getting executed.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks Lynn

Comment: Please show your code. Did you include your `<noscript>` tag correctly in the `<body>` element? Here are [some basic rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript)

Comment: hi blex.. i have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to install something server-side to see how many unique visitors you are serving to.

Then you compare this number to the Google Analytics numbers to see how many of them have JavaScript disabled.

Comment: thanks for responding to me. Installing something server side is something that I can't do. I need to have some script like js script similar to google analytics to track this. I was thinking, if I add a log in  no script tag that will get executed when no js users hit my site.

Comment: google analystics also recommends adding an img src for "non js" users in no-script tag. But when I tested with real traffic to my site, these users are not getting tracked.